# Fast convertions of UNIX time to human readable time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a fast way to convert a column with UNIX timestamps to human readable time. Currently I'm using the following code:

```
#convert unix to human readable form
for i in range(len(df)):
    #df.timestamp[i] = str(pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp  [i],unit='s'))
    df.timestamp[i] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(df.timestamp[i])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: I want to minimize the runtime, so I'm looking for a faster alternative to my code.

Comment: Maybe it's more efficient to assign to `df['timestamp']` rather than writing a `for` loop. But I don't use pandas.

Comment: But most of the time is probably spent in `strftime()`. There's no way to avoid having to call it for every value.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `pandas.to_datetime` to a whole `Series`:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')
```